# win32 bitmap erroneously converted to monochrome

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I'm trying to get the bits of a window icon, in order to send them through a socket. To test if I'm hable to get the BITMAP corresponding to the HICON, I save it on a file.

The problem is that, opening the file where I've saved the bitmap, it appear monochrome (black and white, not grey scale).

Here is the BITMAPINFO struct:

```
info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
info.biWidth = bitmap.bmWidth;
info.biHeight = bitmap.bmHeight;
info.biPlanes = 1;  
info.biBitCount = 32;
info.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
info.biSizeImage = 0;
info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;  
info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;     
info.biClrUsed = 0; 
info.biClrImportant = 0;
```

And I compute the size of the bitmap as:

```
DWORD dwBmpSize2 = ((bitmap.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bitmap.bmHeight;
```

Then:

```
// Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    //Prendo i bit dell'icona
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    GetDIBits(hdc, hbit, 0, (UINT)bitmap.bmHeight, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    wcout « "lpbitmap buffer: "« lpbitmap « endl;

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"captureqwsx.bmp",
      GENERIC_WRITE,
      0,
      NULL,
      CREATE_ALWAYS,
      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    //Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    //Size of the file
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    //bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM   

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: *"it appear monochrome"* - It's not clear, how you deduce that information. Are you dumping the bitmap, and then trying to open it in some tool (like MS Paint)? Are you trying to display it yourself? Besides that, why are you trying to write raw bitmap data instead of using the built-in support (like the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx))?

Comment: @IInspectable I've written that I've saved it in a file, so I can look at it opening that file. For example, the google chrome logo appear all black except the central circle and one of the "triangles" around it, wich are white.
Thanks anyhow for the link, I will study it.

Comment: Since an icon consists of **two** bitmaps, maybe you are extracting the mask (which happens to be a monochrome bitmap by design). No way for us to know, whether you should expect a grayscale image, or really just a monochrome one.

Comment: You are not showing how you get `hbit`.

Comment: @IInspectable that's the answer. I was extracting the mask. Now I use GetIconInfo to get the struct ICONINFO, from wich I can extract both the mask and the color bitmaps. Thanks